# Parallel processing in Azure Event Hubs (multiple consumers on same partition)

Tags: c#, azure, parallel-processing, partitioning, azure-eventhub

Azure Event Hubs allows partitions within a consumer group. In my example, i have two consumers that send out notifications with different logics. I need to decide within the consumer which logic to apply, so each event should be caught by both applications, and then the right logic is decided according to the event data. Originally, i had only one consumer and decided what logic to apply within that one, since there will be more than 2 processing methods in the future, but i have been instructed to have multiple consumers for each processing method, which is not optimal or even achievable at a large scale with only one consumer group.
When i start both consumers, they listen in different partitions, and the events are only caught by one consumer each, therefore i can't guarantee that i will apply the right logic to the event because it doesn't get consumed by both applications. Ideally, i should have two consumer groups, but i'm using the Basic tier, which only allows one. However, in the Microsoft docummentation, it states "[There can be at most 5 concurrent readers on a partition per consumer group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-features)", and from what i understand, if both readers were listenning in the same partition, they would both catch all events. I tried setting the partition in my [EventProcessorClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.messaging.eventhubs.eventprocessorclient?view=azure-dotnet) but i haven't found any way of doing so. Is there any way of defining which partition to read from within the consumer, or is there another way of processing the same event in multiple consumers?

Comment: You cannot use EventProcessorClient (or any of the event processor family) to read from the same partition using the same consumer group.  Each intentionally requests exclusive access to a partition.   You'd need to use one of the lower-level consumer types (PartitionReceiver, EventHubConsumerClient) and manage checkpointing and resilience in your application.

Comment: @JesseSquire Thanks for the response! "EventHubConsumerClient" seems to be working when it comes to reading from the same partition, but i'm not being able to checkpoint using that class. In the Microsoft docs, it says the constructor has an argument for a "CheckpointStore", but in my code, the constructor doesn't accept one. Is there any way around this?
`var consumer = new EventHubConsumerClient(consumerGroup, connectionString, eventHubName, checkpointStore)` 
It tries to assign the "checkpointStore" to "EventHubConsumerClientOptions".

Comment: You're looking at the docs for the wrong language.  In some languages (JavaScript and Python, specifically) the consumer acts as both the simple consumer and a processor.  In .NET, these are distinct types.   As I mentioned, only the processor family handles checkpointing and resilience for you.  Using the consumer or partition receiver, you'll have to do so manually.   For more information:  https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/sdk/eventhub/Azure.Messaging.EventHubs/samples/Sample02_EventHubsClients.md

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the comments @Jesse Squire .
According to this [MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-about#key-architecture-components) creating consumer groups is the best approach to rationally segment your audience so they only see the events they are interested in and we cannot specify which message is sent/ receive  to a specified Consumer group From the [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61401331/how-to-map-incoming-messages-to-a-consumer-group-in-azure-eventhub)

- An Example to how to use EventProcessorClient using the source code from the [MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-dotnet-standard-getstarted-send?tabs=passwordless%2Croles-azure-portal).

```
 string connectionString = "Endpoint=sb://sampath123.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=c";
        string hubName = "sampath";       
        string message = "   ";
        await using (var producerClient = new EventHubProducerClient(connectionString, hubName))
        {
            try
            {
              using EventDataBatch eventBatch = await producerClient.CreateBatchAsync();
               if(!eventBatch.TryAdd(new EventData(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message))))
                {
                    throw new Exception("The message is too large for the batch and cannot be sent.");
                }
                 await producerClient.SendAsync(eventBatch);
```

[image]

- Refer this documents for sending and reading from [Event Hub](https://www.thecodebuzz.com/send-receive-events-from-azure-event-hubs-messaging-eventhubs-architecture/) and
  [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58854909/how-to-receive-latest-message-from-eventhub-in-c-sharp).